# How to Get private Videos from my Vimeo account

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I have videos on vimeo and turned on the private mode so nobody can see my videos on vimeo. Now I have placed some of those videos inside albums and want to access them. but I just don't know how to do that? this is what I have done so far:

```
let webApiUrl = 'https://api.vimeo.com/users/<user_id>/albums/<album_id>/videos;
const { data } = await axios.get(webApiUrl,
                 {
                    headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${access_token}`} 
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Actually I followed the official docs which only mention about `public` scope which helps in accessing public data. So in order to get private data I generated new access token with `private` scope and put it in above mentioned code and got the private data easily.